# Access violation writing location for Pointer?

Tags: class, pointers, struct, complex-numbers

This is my CArray.h:

```
struct CComplexNumber
{
    int rpart, ipart;
};

class CArray
{
protected:
    CComplexNumber* a;
    int size;
public:
    CArray* next;
    void updateElement(int rp, int ip);
};
```

And my CArray.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "CArray.h"

void CArray::updateElement(int rp, int ip)
{
    a->rpart = rp;
    a->ipart = ip;
}
```

And this is a line in main.cpp

```
CArray* first = new CArray();
CArray* cur = first;
cur->updateElement(1,2); //=> Here is the line that causes the bug
```

When I debugged, the cmd crassed. I have to exit and debug each line. When I reached the line above, the compiler stop and appear:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00b1155b in Section03.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Please fix my code and explain why I can't replace the rpart with rp?

Comment: could you please describe your issue in more detail?

Comment: struct in the class is not initialized/malloced/newed put that in the constructor so it allocates some memories and in the destructor it releases.

Comment: @user503413 I have edited, please check again

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik the problem is I don't know what are you saying... :( I've just practised C++ for a few days

Comment: Upon creation of a `CArray`, its member `CComplexNumber* a;` is undefined or null. Accessing it in `updateElement` produces a memory protection violation. Why do you need a pointer there?